# CSS: Horizontal banner, vertical navbar, scrollable content

Tags: html, css, navbar, fixed, vertical-scrolling

See that horizontal logo going across the page? I have that in a div with 100% width, 0 top margin, fixed position. I want it going across the top, with the content visible and scrollable under it. That "underneath" content however not only goes under it like water under a bridge, but for some reason it drags the horizontal logo down towards the middle of the page instead of the top. AND it makes the h1 and h2 tags look like plain text. I've been beating my head against the wall for hours on this.
http://studentweb.gcccd.net/jonathan.reider/midterm/VoidCeremony.com/news.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the logo to stay at the same place while scrolling, use `position: absolute` instead of `position: fixed`. The fact that your logo is not scrolling down is exactly how the fixed position is supposed to work.